# Git conflict - mergetool not configured

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, git

I have had an issue with my project: I forgot to pull the remote branch before working. then I got a conflict with a stylesheet called `application.css`

Though when I pulled the remote branch to origin, all not conflicted files were updated (which was good). Only the above file was marked as conflicting.

My command line tool said I had to fix the conflict before commiting.

I then ran : `git mergetool`

But got an error **mergetool not configured** and then something called `vdiff` was launched.

It is a Windows command line conflict resolving tool but I am a bit lost of what I should do. I have no knowledge of the keys that I may use

[image]

Can you help me fix this ?

Comment: that is `vim`, the text editor. Close it by pressing `Esc` and then `:q!`.
Then to resolve the conflict see here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161813/how-to-resolve-merge-conflicts-in-git

Comment: thanks I have installed diffmerge for windows for further issues and avoid vim

Answer (score -1, accepted):

why don't you just open up it up with something like sublime text and then edit the conflicted application.css file manually?

After the conflict is solved  you'll have to mark the file as resolved by executing

```
 git add <filename>
```

Finally, after solving all conflicts, a merge conflict situation needs to be concluded by a regular commit.

Comment: yeah but now I have pulled, my branch is kind of holding two images of the same file ? The file that I want to keep is the local file. so technically I have nothing to change. I just need to tell git to keep the local file ...

Comment: thanks. after going outside `vim` my file was messed up but I edited it. and added it as you advised and it worked.

Comment: awesome, makes me very happy